# Could not find method ndk() for arguments

Tags: android-ndk

I'm following [Create Hello-JNI With Android Studio](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3).

MAC OX 10.11.5

Android Studio 2.2 stable

java version: 1.7.0_79

gradle-2.14.1

Here's my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chenql.helloandroidjni"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "hello-android-jni"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here's the error:
[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBvXi.png)

```
Error:(20, 0) Could not find method ndk() for arguments [build_13jh6qtzl4f08f8c1of3mvsys$_run_closure1$_closure5@5b127949] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Open File

Comment: I have also added the JNI function getMsgFromJni() and System.loadLibrary() to the end of class MainActivity.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It turns out that this code

```
ndk {
    moduleName "hello-android-jni"
    }
```

should be placed under "defaultConfig" block:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chenql.helloandroidjni"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        moduleName "hello-android-jni"
    }
}
```

instaed of after "buildTypes" block.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe Google hasn't fixed their documentation on this: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2

Comment: Holy crap. Just that. Wew. Thanks you Rock Asian guy.

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to a newer version of the Gradle plugin solves

Answer (score 2):

You just add the following code in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion //<-- add line
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
```

And in `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670 || {{use your ndk_version}}" //<-- add line
```

Thats it. Rebuild the app

Answer (score 2):

Comment or delete ndkVersion 'version number' at build.gradle